# Display Item based on Item order in Content Query Webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part, item-styles

I am displaying Link list item using Content query webpart and I have created Template in ItemStyle.xsl stylesheet for Customised look but I also want to display item based on the order I have given in the Link List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In content query web part there is a property **Presentation > Sort Item by**. Use that to sort your results. Check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St) blog

[image]